# List<Long> is not serialised to String in Java

Tags: java, serialization, objectmapper

We have a class **Agent** with `assignedUsers` as **List<*Long*>**

when we try to convert the object as JSON document, we are using **ObjectMapper** `writeValueAsString` method, which does not serialize the ids into String instead the key **assignedUsers** are not missed in the JSON string.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Agent {
private List<Long> assignedUserIds;
        private String name;

        private static final String json = "{\"name\":\"New Agency\", \"assignedUserIds\":[23,24]}";

        public String getName() {
                return name;
        }

        public void setName(final String name) {
                this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Long> gocuetAssignedUserIds() {
        return assignedUserIds;
        }

        public void setAssignedUserIds(final List<Long> assignedUserIds) {
                this.assignedUserIds = assignedUserIds;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Agent agencyInfo = null;
                try {
                        agencyInfo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Agent.class);
                        System.out.println("Built Agent :: " + new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(agencyInfo)); // Outputs: Built Agent :: {"name":"New Agency"}
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your getter for the field `assignedUserIds` is called `gocuetAssignedUserIds()`. This is why it's not serialized (the mapper does not recognize it), either mark it with the annotiation `@JsonGetter("assignedUserIds")` or rename it to `getAssignedUserIds()` to match the field.

Comment: thank you so much :) this is a test class, in the actual class the getter method was private. kind of embarrassed here!